# Python: Packages, Modules, and Classes - is this approach any good?

Tags: python

After reading a decent amount in this area, I've come up with the following for myself.

- `__init__.py` has imports of all submodules which are intended for outside use; an `__all__` variable which contains a list of all.
- Classes are typically one to a module, though if it makes sense to bundle a few classes into single module, then that's allowed.
- Modules not meant for public use, are not imported in `__init__.py`, and are not listed in its `__all__` member. This deters but does not prevent user code from accessing these non-public modules.
- Any 'runnable' submodules in the package, must to explicit, non-relative imports of any required submodules.
- Running these runnable submodules should be done with `-m`. Eg `python3 -m mypackage.mySubModule`
- Any submodule MAY import the entire module via `from mypackage import *`. It seems fair to allow submodule authors, of having an easy way to get at all the (public) submodules, and fair to trust them to intelligently handle collision issues, to recognize the names of submodules, etc. It also puts the burden on `__init__.py`'s `__all__` **This is the only use of `from foo import *`I tolerate** :)

The biggest drawbacks I can think of are ...

- Non-public submodules are still accessible.
- Submodules explicitly use the package name, so if the package name changes, modules break
- I'm allowing `from foo import *` just this one time, which is about as 'famous last words' as it gets.

I'm happy to hear other issues as well.

Below is a simplified but thorough example. Thanks very much to all.

**File & Directory Layout**

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    A.py           # class A
    B.py           # class B
    _Helper.py     # Helper class used by A and B
    api.py         # public API for mypackage
    runMe.py       # A runnable class inside mypackage (possibly for testing)

userCode.py     # Code that uses mypackage; could be located anywhere
```

**__init__.py**

```
from mypackage.A import A
from mypackage.B import B
from mypackage import api
__all__ = ['A', 'B', 'api']
```

**A.py (and B.py as well)**

```
from mypackage import _Helper

class A:
    def __init__ (self): pass
    def test (self):     _Helper.printMessage()
```

**_Helper.py**

```
def printMessage ():
    print("*** _Helper.printMessage() is reachable ***")
```

**api.py**

```
from mypackage import *

def createA (): return A()
def createB (): return B()
```

**runMe.py**

```
from mypackage import api

a = api.createA()
a.test()

b = api.createB()
b.test()
```

**userCode.py**
    import mypackage

```
a = mypackage.api.createA()
a.test()

b = mypackage.api.createB()
b.test()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you have an actual issue you're trying to solve? If you just want feedback, you should be asking this on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) assuming your code currently works.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I didn't know about CodeReview; I'll try posting there.